# Passing data into "router-outlet" child components

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-routing

I've got a parent component that goes to the server and fetches an object:

```
// parent component

@Component({
    selector : 'node-display',
    template : `
        <router-outlet [node]="node"></router-outlet>
    `
})

export class NodeDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

    node: Node;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.nodeService.getNode(path)
            .subscribe(
                node => {
                    this.node = node;
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }
```

And in one of several childdren display:

```
export class ChildDisplay implements OnInit{

    @Input()
    node: Node;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.node);
    }

}
```

It doesn't seem I can just inject data into the `router-outlet`. It looks like I get the error in the web console:

```
Can't bind to 'node' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'.
```

This somewhat makes sense, but how would I do the following:

1. Grab the "node" data from the server, from within the parent
   component?
2. Pass the data I have retrieved from the server into the child router-outlet?

It doesn't seem like `router-outlets` work the same way.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```ts
<router-outlet [node]="..."></router-outlet>
```

is just invalid. The component added by the router is added as sibling to `<router-outlet>` and does not replace it.

See also https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

```ts
@Injectable() 
export class NodeService {
  private node:Subject<Node> = new BehaviorSubject<Node>([]);

  get node$(){
    return this.node.asObservable().filter(node => !!node);
  }

  addNode(data:Node) {
    this.node.next(data);
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
    selector : 'node-display',
    providers: [NodeService],
    template : `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class NodeDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private nodeService:NodeService) {}
    node: Node;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.nodeService.getNode(path)
            .subscribe(
                node => {
                    this.nodeService.addNode(node);
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

```ts
export class ChildDisplay implements OnInit{
    constructor(nodeService:NodeService) {
      nodeService.node$.subscribe(n => this.node = n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be used to give an ID to the child? I've tried changed all the `node` where it's as a type to `string` and it doesn't seem to work or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You can pass any data to the child component but the child component needs to set the id itself. You can try to get an `ElementRef` from an event from the router outlet to use it to set the id but I don't know by heart if or how to do that (only on my phone)

Comment: It is possible to transfer data through router-outlet directive. We can use "activate" event for this. For more details read my article
See also https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service
See also
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/passing-data-between-components-routing-rajesh-t/

Answer (score 67):

Yes, **you can pass data directly into router outlet components**. Sadly, you cannot do this using angular template binding, as mentioned in other answers. You have to set the data in the typescript file. There's a big caveat to that when observables are involved (described below).

**Here's how:**

**(1)** Hook up to the router-outlet's `activate` event in the parent template:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onOutletLoaded($event)"></router-outlet>
```

**(2)** Switch to the parent's typescript file and set the child component's inputs programmatically each time they are activated:

```
onOutletLoaded(component) {
    component.someProperty = 'someValue';
}
```

**Done.**

However, the above version of `onOutletLoaded` is simplified for clarity. It only works if you can guarantee all child components have the exact same inputs you are assigning. If you have components with different inputs, use type guards:

```
onOutletLoaded(component: MyComponent1 | MyComponent2) {
  if (component instanceof MyComponent1) {
    component.someInput = 123;
  } else if (component instanceof MyComponent2) {
    component.anotherInput = 456;
  }
}
```

**Why may this method be preferred over the service method?**

Neither this method nor the service method are "the right way" to communicate with child components (both methods step away from pure template binding), so you just have to decide which way feels more appropriate for the project.

This method, however, avoids the tight coupling associated with the "create a service for communication" approach (i.e., the parent needs the service, and the children all need the service, making the children unusable elsewhere).

In many cases this method also feels closer to the "angular way" because you can continue passing data to your child components through @Inputs. It's also a good fit for already existing or third-party components that you don't want to or can't tightly couple with your service.

On the other hand, it may feel less like the angular way when...

**Caveat**

The caveat with this method is that since you are passing data in the typescript file, you no longer have the option of using the pipe-async pattern used in templates (e.g. `{{ myObservable$ | async }}`) to automagically use and pass on your observable data to child components.

Instead, you'll need to set up something to get the current observable values whenever the `onOutletLoaded`  function is called. This will likely also require some teardown in the parent component's `onDestroy` function. This is nothing too unusual, there are often cases where this needs to be done, such as when using an observable that doesn't even get to the template.

Comment: Thanks! this is a great answer 

Comment: and what if the `child component` gets activated before the `parent component` finish an `http` request?

Comment: @Kardon63, I don't think that's relevant to this question. What you are describing can happen in many different situations. You should open another question and clarify your specific situation.

Comment: @uɥƃnɐʌuop okk thanks for the clarification

Comment: Decoupling is way to go. But in the example given communication occurs only upon `onOutletLoaded($event)`, unavailable after this `loaded` event. Isn't it?

Comment: @Jeb50, yes, that's correct. Although I would be wary of trying to "communicate" with your child components. This pattern enforces a strict uni-directional communication. The parent should only be sending inputs and your child components decide when an output is appropriate. However, inputs can certainly be sent in after the `onOutletLoaded` when using  observables and/or subjects.

Comment: there is no such thing is called on onChildLoaded in angular Child Component
any thoughts ?

Comment: onChildLoaded   does not fire , any thoughs ?

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada `onChildLoaded` is your custom function that's called via the `activate` event. It's a typo, it should have been: `onOutletLoaded`

Comment: Perfect fit for my case. Thanks!

Comment: can anyone help me. What if in my component I am getting the data via observable and my (activate) from router-outlet fires before my data is ready, then in my component my object will be undefined. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 54):

Günters answer is great, I just want to point out another way without using Observables.

Here we though have to remember that these objects are passed by reference, so if you want to do some work on the object in the child and not affect the parent object, I would suggest using Günther's solution. But if it doesn't matter, or actually is **desired behavior**, I would suggest the following.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    sharedNode = {
      // properties
    };
}
```

In your parent you can assign the value:

```ts
this.sharedService.sharedNode = this.node;
```

And in your children (AND parent), inject the shared Service in your constructor. Remember to provide the service at module level providers array if you want a singleton service all over the components in that module. Alternatively, just add the service in the providers array in the parent **only**, then the parent and child will share the same instance of service.

```ts
node: Node;

ngOnInit() {
    this.node = this.sharedService.sharedNode;    
}
```

And as newman kindly pointed, you can also have `this.sharedService.sharedNode` in the html template or a getter:

```ts
get sharedNode(){
  return this.sharedService.sharedNode;
}
```

Comment: you can/should bind to sharedService.sharedNode in html directly. This way, updates in sharedNode will be kept in sync.

Answer (score 13):

There are 3 ways to pass data from Parent to Children

1. Through shareable service : you should store into a service the data you would like to share with the children
2. Through Children Router Resolver if you have to receive different data

   ```
   this.data = this.route.snaphsot.data['dataFromResolver'];
   ```
3. Through Parent Router Resolver if your have to receive the same data from parent

   ```
   this.data = this.route.parent.snaphsot.data['dataFromResolver'];
   ```

**Note1:** You can read about resolver [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve). There is also an example of resolver and how to register the resolver into the module and then retrieve data from resolver into the component. The resolver registration is the same on the parent and child.

**Note2:** You can read about *ActivatedRoute* [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) to be able to get data from router

Answer (score 11):

## Service:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";    

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
onGetData: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

getData() {
  this.http.post(...params).map(res => {
    this.onGetData.emit(res.json());
  })
}
```

## Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
import {DataService} from "../services/data.service";       
    
@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private DataService:DataService) {
    this.DataService.onGetData.subscribe(res => {
      (from service on .emit() )
    })
  }

  //To send data to all subscribers from current component
  sendData() {
    this.DataService.onGetData.emit(--NEW DATA--);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular/44865817) question, in Angular 7.2 you can pass data from parent to child using the history state. So you can do something like

> Send:
>
> ```
> this.router.navigate(['action-selection'], { state: { example: 'bar' } });
> ```
>
> Retrieve:
>
> ```
> constructor(private router: Router) {
>   console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example);
> }
> ```

But be careful to be consistent. For example, suppose you want to display a list on a left side bar and the details of the selected item on the right by using a router-outlet. Something like:

---

Item 1 (x) | ..............................................

Item 2 (x) | ......Selected Item Details.......

Item 3 (x) | ..............................................

Item 4 (x) | ..............................................

---

Now, suppose you have already clicked some items. Clicking the browsers back buttons will show the details from the previous item. But what if, meanwhile, you have clicked the (x) and delete from your list that item? Then performing the back click, will show you the details of a deleted item.

Answer (score 3):

There is another different way. I believe my way solves many problems :

this is the default way of handling the routes :

```
{ path: 'sample/page1', component: sampleComponent1 },
{ path: 'sample/page2', component: sampleComponent2 },
{ path: 'sample/page3', component: sampleComponent3 },
```

but instead of that, let's write the routes like below :

```
{ path: 'sample/:sub', component: sampleComponent },
```

as you can see, we combined routes and made a route-parameter. we can recieve that parameter value on the component :

```
// sampleComponents.ts :
sub = this.route.snapshot.params['sub'];
```

now on the html file for that component we import those pages as sub-components. then we can send data directly to them.

```
// sampleComponent.html :
<app-cmp-page1 *ngIf="sub==='page1'" [data]="data"></app-cmp-page1>
<app-cmp-page2 *ngIf="sub==='page2'" [data]="data"></app-cmp-page2>
<app-cmp-page3 *ngIf="sub==='page3'" [data]="data"></app-cmp-page3>
```