# How to dynamically change a class from a router-outlet inner component by using an Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

With learning purpose I have got an scenario and trying to use a service able to dynamically change the class of a component generated by router-outlet.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451375/passing-data-into-router-outlet-child-components-angular-2) I have the service with a BehaviorSubject which value is toggled by a function.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DynamicClassesService {
    private stateRouterOutlet: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('am-topMenu');

    stateRouterOutlet$ = this.stateRouterOutlet.asObservable();

    toggleStateRouterOutlet() {
        let current;
        this.stateRouterOutlet.subscribe(res => { current = res });
        current = (current === 'am-topMenu' ? 'am-leftMenu' : 'am-topMenu');
        this.stateRouterOutlet.next(current);
        console.log('Toggled to: ' + current);
    }
```

I need help for the next step. I do subscribe from the child component and I get the value in constructor and store in a local (of the component) variable  as it follow. (Maybe it is wrong)

Have any sense if I declare it (*localStateRouterOutlet*) as `@Input()`?

```
localStateRouterOutlet: string;

 constructor(private dynamicClasses: DynamicClassesService) {
        dynamicClasses.stateRouterOutlet$.subscribe(res => {
            this.localStateRouterOutlet = res;
            console.log(this.localStateRouterOutlet);
        })
    }
```

Where is the clue to manage that toggle function from the service have effect in this variable?

If I bind

```
[ngClass] = "localStateRouterOutlet"
```

Is it supposed to work for my initial purpose?
This is the totally wrong concept?

I do apreciate you help in advance.

Comment: you could try `[ngClass]="stateRouterOutlet$ | asnyc"`

Comment: when toggleStateRouterOutlet is called?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried binding with async pipe as you said and it didn't work but I want to give another try with time and I will come to say what happens. Thank you very much from now, it was usefull and I feel it should resolve by anyway.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova I am calling togleStateRouterOutlet directly from a button (click) on my root component template. It component loads the service.