# Passing Reactive Forms group into router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am trying to share my Reactive Forms across many components, and I am running into an issue when trying to accomplish that via routing. The error I am receiving: 
'Can't bind to 'group' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'

Here is the router:

```html
<router-outlet [group]="turnoverService.turnoverForm"></router-outlet>
```

Is there a way to accomplish passing Reactive Forms to child components with routing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the binding syntax in Angular (`[]`) will only work if the component has an `@Input` property with the same name as the binding. `router-outlets` don't have this. Plus, the routed component is added as a sibling to `<router-outlet>`, not a child.

The easiest way (and best practice IMO) is to just use a shared service that has the data that is then injected into the child components. It looks like you have a `turnoverService`, so the child components would need to grab this in their constructor.

More info: [Passing data into "router-outlet" child components (angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451375/passing-data-into-router-outlet-child-components-angular-2)

**EDIT**: Another way to do this would be to use the `resolve` method on the route definitions themselves. The `resolve` function will fire when the route is activated, but the route itself will not actually load until the `resolve` function successfully completes. The routed component will then have access to the `resolve` data via the `Injector`. This would work if you already have the data or need to do some logic to get it, but probably isn't the best solution if the `resolve` method is making asynchronous AJAX calls.

More info on `resolve` in this excellent [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html) (the Angular docs themselves are lacking here).