# pass data through <router-outlet> using component interaction in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-components, router-outlet

I'm trying to use this technique [intercept input property changes with a setter](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter) to pass some data from a parent component to a child component and call a method in child component when the value is changed. my problem is the child component is binded to the parent by `<router-link>` and when I try to  pass the data using:

**parent_component.html :**

```
<router-outlet [some_value] = "some_value"></router-outlet>
```

where some_value is the parameter I am trying to pass from parent to child.

**parent_component.ts :**

```
public some_value: string;
```

and

**parent_component.ts :**

```
@Input()
  public set some_vale(number : string){
    this._some_value = number;
  }
```

however I get the error

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'some_value' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'.

what am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to pass the data from parent to child component when using a `<router-outlet>`?

Thanks in advance and any help appreciated.

Comment: until now, there is no property binding in <router-outlet>, you can use services in order to communicate between components.

Comment: so there is simply no way to do this?

Comment: I think you can't do that this way. If you want to send data from the router to the child, declare a Service and use a Observable to send your object. You'll do a .next(your-object) on the component where the router is declared, and a .subscribe(object => {...}); on the child component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data into "router-outlet" child components (angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451375/passing-data-into-router-outlet-child-components-angular-2)

Comment: no, bcs when using property binding, you bind a property which surly must be exist, but you cant make sure that it will be exist in  <router-outlet>.

Comment: I will use services then. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Service:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";    

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
onGetData: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

getData() {
  this.http.post(...params).map(res => {
    this.onGetData.emit(res.json());
  })
}
```

## Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
import {DataService} from "../services/data.service";       
    
@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private DataService:DataService) {
    this.DataService.onGetData.subscribe(res => {
      (from service on .emit() )
    })
  }

  //To send data to all subscribers from current component
  sendData() {
    this.DataService.onGetData.emit(--NEW DATA--);
  }
}
```