# Angular4 Passing data from parent to child, emit not working

Tags: angular, input, eventemitter, emit, ng2-smart-table

I'm trying to emit data from the parent component to the child component, however I'm facing a problem with my ng2-smart-table that is in the way of emitting. In my parent component I make use of the ng2-smart-table, which uses userRowSelect (a standard function), when I select a row in the table, I get all the data from that row. The data from that row I want to pass to my child component. I tried using a shared service, input and emitting, none of them have worked so far. Below are code snippets of the two components. Any suggestions on what to do?

Parent html:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data" (userRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Parent component:

```
@Output() passDataToViewPdf: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
      this.reportService.getReportsTemplates().subscribe(response => this.data = response);
  }

  onRowSelect(event): void {
      this.passDataToViewPdf.next(event);
      this.router.navigate(['/report-view-pdf', localStorage.getItem('siteId')]);
  }
```

Child component:

```
    @Input() template;

    public handleEvent(event) {
            // get data from passDataToViewPdf emitter
        }
    ngOnInit() { this.template = // get data from handleEvent}
```

Comment: An Output is used to emit, from a child, an event that can be received by the parent. It seems you're trying to emit from a parent an event to the child. That's simply not how angular works. Inputs are used to pass data from parent to child.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451375/passing-data-into-router-outlet-child-components-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

That's because Angulars `EventEmitter` has `emit` method to emit value. Look at [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#examples)

It should be

```
this.passDataToViewPdf.emit(event);
```

However looking at your code `EventEmitter` is defined in parent component, so your parent component is emitting value to it's parent not to child.

It should look like this.

Child component

```
@Input() template;
@Input() set pdf(newPdf) {
   this._pdf = newPdf;
   this.handleEvent(newPdf);
};
private _pdf;



public handleEvent(event) {
    // process your data
}
ngOnInit() { this.template = // get data from handleEvent}
```

Parent html template

```
<child-component [pdf]="pdfValueInParent"></child-component>
```

Parent component ts

```
onRowSelect(event): void {
      this.pdfValueInParent = event;
      this.router.navigate(['/report-view-pdf', localStorage.getItem('siteId')]);
  }
```

Comment: I load my child component on a different page, I route to that page via the onRowSelect function in the parent (/report-view-pdf). I don't include the child-component-selector in the parent-html itself. How do I still get the data to my child without including the selector in the parent-html?

Comment: Well, then you can do it by several way, first of all would be `service` that store data and share it. If it's small data then you can use `localStorage`, or try to pass it via `router`. The quickest and safest would be store data to `service` and then fetch it from `service` inside `child-component`. (By `service` I mean small `angular service` or you can make `singleton`)

Comment: I have a shared service already, routing or localStorage is not an option, since I have to pass a lot of json-data. I can use the shared service for a large amount of data, so far I have only used it in my app to pass just one value from component to component?

Comment: Then use your `shared service`. It will be the best option. It shouldn't be a trouble to store one more variable :)

Comment: Next problem: I have my shared service, but when subscribing to the observable it always returns null in my child component. Does routing cause the issue?

Comment: As long as you do not refresh page should be fine or and staying in current angular site.

Comment: Ach, it could be also that after redirect to child-component it just subscribe and from now on it's waiting for change. You have to initialy fetch data from shared service.