# Is it possible to pass the route ID from one component to a different component dialog in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My app.component.html looks as follows:

```html
<app-header></app-header>


  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am trying to have a component from my router-outlet section pass its URL id to a dialog I have in my app-header.

```
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

This will produce a 2 when my url is website.com/dash/2.

How can I pass the 2 to my dialog (that exists in app-header)? I know how to do this when the dialog is in the same component but have never had luck when they exist like the way I described above.

Comment: You can use service, to pass the data (in your case the id) from one place to another.

Comment: yes, use a service, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585082/how-to-implement-nested-secondary-routing-and-still-get-the-data-from-child-ang/50592366#50592366)

Comment: use localStorage or a service