# Angular-5 how to get data from multiple children to parent using single event?

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I have a scenario where i have 3 tabs in my web page, where in tab content area three different components loads on activation of each tab(say components 'ABC','PQR','XYZ'). In the main page in which tabs are present i have to show some header data related to the tab content loaded in the tab.
Suppose if tab `BAC` is loaded, i have to show some message sent from `ABC`component, likewise for all three components.

I tried with single component but my event listner is not working.

Main Tabs Page(Parent Component):
HTML File **tabs.component.html**:

```
 <h1>{{headerMessage}}</h1>

<my-tabs [items]="tabItems">
    <router-outlet (tabHeaderTextEvent)="receiveHeaderText($event)"></router-outlet>
</my-tabs>
```

**tabs.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabItem } from '@MYCOMPONENTS/tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'MYPAGE-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.scss']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {
  public headerMessage: String;
  public tabItems: TabItem[] = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.tabItems = [{
      routerPath: 'abc',
      label: 'ABC_LABEL',
    }, {
      routerPath: 'PQR',
      label: 'PQR_LABEL',
      disabled: true
    },
    {
      routerPath: 'XYZ',
      label: 'XYZ_LABEL',
      disabled: true
    }];
  }

  receiveHeaderText($event) {
    console.log('***********************************');
    console.log($event);
    this.headerMessage = $event;
  }
}
```

**Child.component.ts** (from where i wish to send data):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'someSelector',
  templateUrl: './sometemplate.component.html'
})
export class Child implements OnInit {
  @Output() tabHeaderTextEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.tabHeaderTextEvent.emit('hello from overview component');
  }
}
```

Likewise i have two more components those are emitting `tabHeaderTextEvent`event on its constructor call.
But i my listener function in my tab component is never getting called.
Can anyone guide me where i am going wrong ? 
**OR** 
Any better approach to achieve the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't pass data via bindings on the `router-outlet`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451375/passing-data-into-router-outlet-child-components-angular-2 While this question relates to input data, the same is true for output data. You'll likely need a shared service to get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Injector.

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { MyPageComponent } from "./mypage.component";
export class Child implements OnInit
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        let parentComponent = this.injector.get(MyPageComponent);
        parentComponent.receiveHeaderText('String');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against this.

Comment: @ritaj, can you please explain if there are any bad consequences of injecting a paent component into child and accessing the properties from child. If this is bad practice , then why is it so?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, Thanks. While googling  i did not found this way of data sharing between parent and child (may not be recommended) , but this solution worked for my scenario. Your solution is like we are accessing parent component properties into child component. Let me see if some better solution comes, if not i will accept your answer currently i have up voted it .