# Angular 8: Passing object to route table

Tags: angular

In app.component.html I have a tab menu:

```html
    <... [tabsData]="tabsData">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </...>
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```js
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', children: [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'prefix', redirectTo: 'son'},
      {path: 'son', component: SonComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

Is it possible to pass 'this' (or any other object) of the parent to the son component ?
How ?

In "regular" parent and son I did it in the parent with:

in the parent's HTML. 
and used @Input in the son.

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: I think this has been already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/41451466/11719787

Comment: Hi Sameer. Thank you very much !