# How to update Angular app component from child component

Tags: angular

I know there are a few different answers out there that are similar, but I haven't found something exactly what I'm looking for.

See below.

### app.component.html

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="sidepanel">
     <!-- update here -->
  </div>
  <div id="content">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is that I'd like for a child page component (loaded by the router) to update the content in the side panel.

I know I could create a service, but I'd like to add HTML to the parent component directly. I guess I'm looking for something like how Asp.Net MVC/Razor allows you to specify multiple content blocks for the parent template.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: "I know I could create a service" - what's wrong with that ?

Comment: You might looking for hand craft like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58720658/11634381

Comment: So the child route components should be able to set their "owned" template to the sidepanel area, is that correct? Sounds to me like in your case the `router-outlet` should be directly under `#main` div, so that the `#sidepanel` div gets set by each component as needed.

Comment: When you has a `<router-outlet>` you has **no** children relationship. You should use a service with a subject

Comment: You could could use named router-outlet to project sidebar content based on the reoute.   But anyway, what is wrong with shared service layer?