# Pass data to children component in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular and I have two children components and I wanna pass data to them. Here is how I wrote my code: This is the home template

```
<div class="myCard">
    <mat-card style="width: 500px;">
      <mat-card-title style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:space-between">
        <span>Employees</span>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/home/add-employee">Add</button>
      </mat-card-title>
      <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

Then on the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that's where the children components show. I know how to pass data to child if I included only one child component like `<app-child [data]="data"></app-child>` in place of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on the code above. So I wanna know how can I achieve this the way I want

**Update**
Thanks guys, but I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451375/passing-data-into-router-outlet-child-components)

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to pass data to components injected by angular's router. You can pick what you want according to your needs:

**1. You want to pass static data to the child (only depending on the route)**

In order to achieve this, you can just pass the `data` property to your route config, which can then be retrieved by your child component via `ActivatedRoute.data`

**2. You want to pass data from the parent component (the one including the `router-outlet`) to a child injected by Angular router**

This can be achieved by setting the `state` property (available from Angular 7.2.0 on) in your `navigate` call like

`this.router.navigate(['your-child-route'], { state: 'your-data' });`.

You can then read it in your child component by using

`this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state`.

If you are navigating by using `routerLink` in your template, you can pass the state as a property: `[state]="'your-data'"`

**3. Use a service to receive and propagate the values.**

You can also use a service, which can receive data, write it to a Subject and then use the child component to subscribe to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component Html

```
<div class="myCard">
    <mat-card style="width: 500px;">
      <mat-card-title style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:space-between">
        <span>Employees</span>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/home/add-employee">Add</button>
      </mat-card-title>
      <app-child1 [data]="data" ></app-child1>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

Parent Component ts file

```
data:any=[]; // any data that you want to pass from parent.
```

---

Child component ts file

```
@Input() data: any = [];
```